# Querying Google for iOS SDK API documentation by class name returns links to that class from the Mac OS X Library. Why? How can I avoid this?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, search-engine

Take CATransition as an example.

Why does Google return those results and not learn that I actually need the iOS reference library and is there a way to make it return the proper results for me?

It usually works by adding the ios keyword in the search query, but it's annoying. I generally return to the search results and click the link from the iOS Reference Library, or do another query with *ios* at the end and this brings me to the needed page, but I would expect the search engine to learn that I am not interested in the Mac OS X Reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably too much to expect a search engine to tailor its results to your behavior, too many people use the same computers often without logging out of their Google account for it to be reliable.

However there is a quick fix, just make a slight change in the address bar once you're in the OSX reference.

http://developer.apple.com/library/***mac***/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Can be switched to
http://developer.apple.com/library/***ios***/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Works for me every time.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I generally just add ios as a keyword and it does the trick ... it's shorter than changing the url, but your solution works too and I appreciate the elaborate answer.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it just comes down to personal preference. Like you, I sometimes forget to include 'iOS' in the initial query and don't usually realize my mistake until I'm already in the API docs. Double clicking on 'mac' and then typing 'ios' saves the trip back to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Add `site:developer.apple.com/library/ios` to your Google queries. Or do the search in Xcode's documentation browser.